# fluent-bit: [error] [input:tail:tail.0] read error, check permissions: /var/log/containers/*.log" in Azure Red Hat Openshift

Tags: azure, openshift, fluent-bit

I'm newguy in Openshift, and trying to install fluent-bit to collect logs from applications.

I've installed fluent-bit via this helm using [this](https://%5B2022/08/24%2015:34:56%5D%20%5Berror%5D%20%5Binput:tail:tail.0%5D%20read%20error,%20check%20permissions:%20/var/log/containers/*.log) documentation.

`daemonSet` starts and looks good but in logs of `fluent-bit` I see

```
[2022/08/24 15:33:56] [ warn] [input:tail:tail.0] error scanning path: /var/log/containers/*.log
[2022/08/24 15:34:56] [error] [input:tail:tail.0] read error, check permissions: /var/log/containers/*.log
```

Not sure where I've mistaken in configuration or what additional steps I need.

I've tried to play with `SCC` and set different values in `fsGroup, runAs, SELinux` and even tried to add `sa default` to `privileged` SCC. Nothing did help.

```
OpenShift version: 4.10.15
Fluent-bit version: 1.9.7
```